# "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, datetime

estoy desarrollando un blog, en laravel 5.7+, con MySQL 5.7+.
El punto es que me genera este error, CUANDO INTENTO REGISTRAR UN USUARIO Y LA UNICA MANERA DE REGISTRARLO ES COLOCAR: `public $timestamps = false;` porque dice que no estan creada las columnas 'update_at' y 'create_at', y si estan esas tablas en la BD.

Error que muestra Postman:
"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `surname`, `email`, `password`, `role`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Kelvis, Ruiz, kelvisruiz@gmail.com, 03ac674216f3e15c761ee1a5e255f067953623c8b388b4459e13f978d7c846f4, ROLE_USER, 2022-09-25 16:49:13, 2022-09-25 16:49:13))"

Codigo de metodo para registrar usuario:

```
public function register(Request $request) {

        //OBTENER DATOS DE USUARIOS
        $json = $request->input('json', null); //Obtiene informacion del Json y Revisa si el Json es null(vacio)

        $params = json_decode($json); //Convierte el Json en Objeto
        $params_array = json_decode($json, true); //Convierte el Json en Array
        
        
        if (!empty($params) && !empty($params_array)) { //Si no esta vacio el Json:
            //LIMPIAR DATOS
            $params_array = array_map('trim', $params_array); //Elimina los espacios en los campos para que todo OK
            //VALIDAR DATOS DE USUARIO
            $validate = \Validator::make($params_array, [
                        'name' => 'required|alpha',
                        'surname' => 'required|alpha', //Ver documentacion de laravel para las validaciones
            /*#####*/   'email' => 'required|email|unique:users', //Email unico para cada usuario
                        'password' => 'required'
            ]);
           
            if ($validate->fails()) {
                //Validacion ha fallado
                $data = array(//Si hay un campo mal, lo muestra     
                    'status' => 'error',
                    'code' => '404',
                    'message' => 'Usuario no creado.',
                    'errors' => $validate->errors()
                );
            } else {
                //Validacion pasada correctamente
                
                //CIFRAR PASSWORD 
                $pwd = hash('sha256', $params_array['password']); //metodo para cifrar
                
                //COMPROBAR USUARIO DUPLICADO
                /* 'email' => 'required|email|unique:users' ver -> ##### mas arriba*/
                
                //CREAR USUARIO
                $user = new User();
                $user->name = $params_array['name'];
                $user->surname = $params_array['surname'];
                $user->email = $params_array['email'];
                $user->password = $pwd;
                $user->role = 'ROLE_USER';
                
                
                //GUARDAR EL USUARIO EN LA BASE DE DATOS
                $user->save();
                
                $data = array(//Si todo esta bien, lo muestra
                    'status' => 'success',
                    'code' => '200',
                    'message' => 'Usuario creado satisfactoriamente.',
                    'user' => $user
                );
            }
        }else{ //Si esta vacio:
            $data = array(//Si hay un campo mal, lo muestra     
                'status' => 'error',
                'code' => '404',
                'message' => 'Hubo un problema con los datos enviados. Corrige para continuar.'
            );
        }

        return response()->json($data, $data['code']);
    }
```

Codigo de User.php

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    
    public $timestamps = false; //DESACTIVA EL PROBLEMA CON UPDATE_AT / CREATE_AT
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'surname', 'description', 'email', 'password'
    ];

    
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

NO SE QUE ESTOY HACIENDO MAL :(, NO QUIERO DEJAR EL TIMESTAMP EN FALSE YA QUE NECESITO LAS FECHAS EN LAS QUE SE CREEN LOS USUARIOS PARA OTRAS FUNCIONES.

ESPERO QUE LA RESOLUCION DE MI PROBLEMA AYUDE A OTRAS PERSONAS AL IGUAL QUE LOS CODIGOS QUE COMPARTI.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrarnos la estructura de tu tabla `users`? El mensaje de error es claro: las columnas no existen en esa tabla. Ten cuidado de no confundirla con una eventual tabla `users` de la base de datos en sí misma para manejar los usuarios, los niveles de acceso, etc.